# The `.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type `method group' (CS0023) (CurrencyConverter.Droid)

Tags: c#, xamarin

I can't seem to get this to work:

```
public string Convert(){
        var output = "";

        if(input.Length < 1){
            output = "Enter a number!";
        } 
        else {
            try {
                var result = Convert.ToDouble(input) * 0.69;
                output = "$ " + input + " converted to £ " + result;
            } catch(Exception e){
                output = "Enter a number!";
                Console.WriteLine ("Error in conversion: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        return output;

    }
```

I just want to get the var result part to work but I get the below error no matter what.

> Error CS0023: The '.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type `method group' (CS0023) (CurrencyConverter.Droid)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be using `decimal` instead of `double` for financial transactions/conversions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is called `Convert` and is clashing names with `System.Convert`.  You'll need to fully qualify the call to `Convert.ToDouble`:

```
var result = System.Convert.ToDouble(input) * 0.69;
```

Currently it thinks you're trying to apply `.` to your `Convert` method, hence the error you're seeing.

Comment: Omg I never even saw that ><! Now I feel stupid xD. Thank you though. Always helpful to have some eyes on it other then my own!

Comment: In cases like this it may help to do F12 (or 'Go To Definition') on the object that seems to be causing the problem. In this case it would have jumped to the header of your own method.

Comment: @SmiffyKmc Just tagging you so you see Peter's response - that indeed is a good way to help track these things down.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks James and Peter :). Really helpful guys :)